# Checking multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a list of offices to visit in this code from one table in checkbox input format

```
<?php foreach($result_Select as $destination) :?>
    <div class="checkbox-office">
        <label for="checkbox"><?= $destination['OfficeName']?></label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="input-office[]" value="<?= $destination['OfficeName']?>">
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

then I have a sequence of offices visited stored in a row on another table in this format "Engineering Office, HR Office, & Design Office".

I'm having difficulties displaying the value of the sequence of offices visited in the list of checkboxes.

I tried using this code

```
$isChecked = in_array($destination['OfficeName'], $officeArray) ? 'checked' : '';
```

but it didn't work. How do I recode this?

Comment: Before your foreach loop, convert the string of visited offices into an array.

Comment: You shouldn't put a comma-separated list in a table. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: You're not using `$isChecked` in the loop that displays the checkboxes.